# Autostart ubuntuOne on headless server

Tags: autostart, headless

I've set up UbuntuOne on my headless server using this guide

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Headless

however i get disconnected every time i log off and I have to connect it manually each time i log into my server.

I want it to autostart and be online all the time even if im not logged into the server.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `screen` or `tmux` to keep things running, while you are not connected to the server. See their man pages for more info. There is also `byobu` which may be of interest to you.

Comment: I don't get it.. how can I use any of these to start ubuntuone at boot? (not at login)

Comment: You can't. You will have to log in once to start it. Ubuntu One file sync is not a system level service, but a per-user service.

Comment: that doesn't seem very practical. then it's pretty useless on a server

Comment: Ubuntu One doesn't officially support running in a headless configuration.

Comment: Okay but I don't understand why not - how hard can it be to make.
I can see a lot of uses for an online folder on a server.